# Looking for code that makes this contract pay out dividends

Tags: solidity, contract-design, tokens, openzeppelin

I have used OpenZeppelin contracts to create a token in Remix that I can mint and send around:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.5.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.5.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";

contract GGCoin is ERC20, ERC20Detailed {

    address owner;

    constructor () public ERC20Detailed("GGCoin", "GGC", 2) {
        _mint(msg.sender, 100000);
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function mint(uint256 amount) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _mint(msg.sender, amount);
    }

}
```

Now I would like to add a dividend function (address X owns Y% of tokens, at the end of the month address X receives Y% of the dividends).

Is there any battle-tested code like the Open Zeppelin contracts available for this?

Comment: You do realize that the dividends will not be added to the balance mapping by themselves at the end of each month, i.e., you (or an "Oracle" server that you set up) will have to initiate that periodically at the end of each month... right?

Comment: Are you going to pay dividends in the same tokens, or in some other tokens/plain ether?

Answer (score 1):

There are non-obvious design considerations. It is not trivial.

**Option 1 - Trustful Process**

You have already re-introduced centralization into your token by giving the `owner` the extraordinary privilege of minting new tokens for itself without restriction. If that is a concern, i.e. likely unacceptable to holders, then you need to eliminate that privilege.

On the other hand, **if the privilege is not a concern and cost is also not a concern**, then the owner can `mint()` new tokens and `transfer()` to each recipient (at the owner's expense). No one can be sure the `owner` will actually do what is expected and won't abuse the privilege but `mint()` neatly addresses the hidden question of where the tokens are sourced from. They have to come from somewhere.

Relying on an external process to iterate over the accounts and pay interest sidesteps the issue of iterating inside the contract, which you should not do: [Getting Loopy with Solidity](https://blog.b9lab.com/getting-loopy-with-solidity-1d51794622ad?gi=1d757c200408).

- Easy to code
- Easy to understand
- Costs the owner gas to send the distributions
- Requires everyone trusts the owner explicitly

**Option 2 - Trustless Process**

A Trustless Process will have no privileged user - no owner. Whatever the `owner` might be doing would be replaced by a deterministic algo. `mint()` is still allowed (setting aside economic implications) but it will have to be the contract itself that decides how many to mint.

A reserve from which to draw the dividends could be set aside, and the contract could draw from that. But, you will find no reserve is large enough to pay interest in perpetuity from a fixed amount. It will just be a countdown to eventual failure, which is not good. Other esoteric patterns could be considered, but let us say the dividends will be paid with new tokens, from `mint()`.

The next challenge is to actually pay it. The intuitive way to approach that is to iterate over each account and give them freshly minted tokens, but you can't do that.

Process Amortization is a solution to this problem.

The idea is to take a large process that you can't do and break it down into a lot of little processes that you can do. In this case, a little "just in time" processing will do the trick.

Consider the following assertion:

> Given a balance at a point in time and knowledge of the dividends paid since that time, it is possible to calculate the balance at the present point in time if we are certain nothing else has happened.

Account balances are cognitively simple. They increase and decrease as funds are received and sent. A dividend payment is a special type that rains down on all accounts.

Every transfer and balance check involves knowing the initial balance making adjustments. We will add another function to calculate dividends or interest received since it was last calculated. This `adjustedBalance()` function will also:

1. Update the stored the balance.
2. Expand the total supply to account for the tokens issued.
3. Update the account timestamp so dividends are paid only once.
4. Return the adjusted account balance.

This can be used *on the fly* in both `view` functions and mutating functions. The changes will not "stick" unless someone is paying for gas, but that can be account doing a `transfer()`. Since `transfer()` will rely on `adjustedBalance()`, this will have the effect of performing housekeeping on both the sender's and receiver's account.

ERC20's `balanceOf()` and `totalSupply()` should return adjusted results.

This is not a trivial thing to tackle but it can be done. In case my explanation is confusing, have a look Nick Johnson's description which I think is the first mention of the generalized approach: https://medium.com/@weka/dividend-bearing-tokens-on-ethereum-42d01c710657

Process Amortization is useful for a wide range of problems that intuitively make one want to iterate inside the contract.

Hope it helps.